# "Review Against" Expression

Tags: expressions

I have an software application that I need to "review against" a set of security guidelines. This seems clear to me, but a colleague questioned this usage.

One alternative would be to review the application "per" the guidelines.

Are there other alternatives? What is the best way to convey this action?

Comment: You could review the software application ***in the context of*** a set of security guidelines or similar, but I don't see why your colleague should object to ***against*** in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative to "review X against Y" is "review X to ensure compliance with Y."

Or, in your specific case, "review the application to ensure compliance with the security guidelines."

Comment: To *review against* is wholly comprehensible, if rather unusual.

When your colleague questioned that usage did he explain why?

If the alternative would be to review the application *per* the guidelines what, exactly, did either of you think *per* added that the original *review against* failed to convey?

There are no *other alternatives*; never. Whatever is the best way to convey your action, there can never be more than two *alternatives* for anything.